# Visual Studio 15 Android "error: undefined reference to"

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

I've built static libraris ( *.a ), added them to my VS project for android. If I call function from one of library - it works good. But when a function from one static library calls a function from another static library - it causes error :  "undefined reference to"

Comment: Please provide a proof of concept and the output errors: with some code you are more likely to get help.

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you.

Answer (score 1):

Open properties page on the *second* library project. Move to Linker -> All options. Find "Additional options" property. By default it should be empty for all Platforms and Configurations.

To solve problem with **cmath** functions, f.e. "error : undefined reference to 'sinf'", add to "Additional options" **-lm** key

To solve problem with **zlib.h** functions, f.e. "error : undefined reference to 'zlibVersion'", add to "Additional options" **-lz** key

I think that there is much more helpful keys

UPDATE: Look on https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html. There is a list of additional keys, where **LOCAL_LDLIBS** is analog of "Additional options" property (I quess)